# ReactJS - How to Handle callbacks? 2nd function is calling before the 1st statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date picker which I have to pass month and year to API from this picker. After extraction of month and year, i have to call a function where API will call.

Before taking the month and date, API is calling. I tried to handle by using .then but of no use.

Please help me handle this

My code as follows:
Here this.getWindTurbineData(); function is calling before passing the date

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.getWindTurbineData();
  }

  getWindTurbineData = () => {
    let month = this.state.mm;
    let year = this.state.yyyy;
    let getTurbineUrl = `url_year?month=${month}&year=${year}`;
    axios.get(getTurbineUrl).then((response) => {
      let res = response.data;
      });
     this.setState({ turbineData: res });
    });
  };

  handleDate = (day) => {
    var mmyy = new Date(day);
    mmyy = JSON.stringify(mmyy);
    let mm = mmyy.slice(6, 8);
    let yyyy = mmyy.slice(1, 5);
    this.setState({ mm, yyyy }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.yyyy, this.state.mm);
    });
    this.getWindTurbineData();
   /*
   this.setState({ mm, yyyy }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.yyyy, this.state.mm);
    }).then(()=>{  this.getWindTurbineData(); });
  */
  };
```